# Transform and fill a dataframe depending on occurence of values within the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
Names1 Gene_name Status
SP1    GENE1     0
SP1    GENE1     1
SP1    GENE1     1
SP1    GENE1     2
SP1    GENE1     2
SP1    GENE2     0
SP3    GENE2     0
SP1    GENE2     1
SP2    GENE2     2
SP4    GENE3     1
SP4    GENE3     2
SP5    GENE3     0    
SP5    GENE3     0
```

Then I would like to fill a new dataframe where each `Gene_name` is a column, and each `Names` is a row :

```
Names GENE1  GENE2 GENE3
SP1   
SP2   
SP3   
SP4   
SP5
```

and fill cells `Values` depending on the `Satus` for each `Names` groups

- if only 0 > value = 0
- if only 1 > value = 1
- if both 0 & 1 > value = 0-1
- if both 0 & 2 > value = 0-2
- if both 1 & 2 > value = 1-2
- if both 0 & 1 & 2 > value = 0-1-2

So for example `GENE1` in `SP1` both present a 0,1 and 2 status, so I fill `0-1-2` within the cell:

```
Names GENE1  GENE2 GENE3
SP1   0-1-2
SP2   
SP3   
SP4   
SP5
```

then, `SP2,SP3,SP4 and SP5` do not have value for the `GENE1`, so I put `NA` :

```
Names GENE1  GENE2 GENE3
SP1   0-1-2
SP2   NA
SP3   NA
SP4   NA
SP5   NA
```

---

Then for the `GENE2:`

`GENE2` in `SP1` both present a 0 and 1 status, so I fill `0-1` within the cell:

```
Names GENE1  GENE2 GENE3
SP1   0-1-2  0-1
SP2   NA
SP3   NA
SP4   NA
SP5   NA
```

`GENE2` in `SP2` present only a value 2 status, so I fill `2` within the cell:

```
Names GENE1  GENE2 GENE3
SP1   0-1-2  0-1
SP2   NA     2
SP3   NA
SP4   NA
SP5   NA
```

`GENE2` in `SP3` present only a value 0 status, so I fill `0` within the cell:

```
Names GENE1  GENE2 GENE3
SP1   0-1-2  0-1
SP2   NA     2
SP3   NA     0
SP4   NA
SP5   NA
```

and the other Names have no `GENE2` values, so I put `NA`:

```
Names GENE1  GENE2 GENE3
SP1   0-1-2  0-1
SP2   NA     2
SP3   NA     0
SP4   NA     NA
SP5   NA     NA
```

and so on...
At the end I should get a full dataframe such as :

```
Names GENE1  GENE2 GENE3
SP1   0-1-2  0-1   NA 
SP2   NA     2     NA
SP3   NA     0     NA
SP4   NA     NA    0-2
SP5   NA     NA    0
```

Does someone have an idea please ?

Here is the dict format of the dataframe if it can helps :

```
{'Names1': {0: 'SP1', 1: 'SP1', 2: 'SP1', 3: 'SP1', 4: 'SP1', 5: 'SP1', 6: 'SP3', 7: 'SP1', 8: 'SP2', 9: 'SP4', 10: 'SP4', 11: 'SP5', 12: 'SP5'}, 'Gene_name': {0: 'GENE1', 1: 'GENE1', 2: 'GENE1', 3: 'GENE1', 4: 'GENE1', 5: 'GENE2', 6: 'GENE2', 7: 'GENE2', 8: 'GENE2', 9: 'GENE3', 10: 'GENE3', 11: 'GENE3', 12: 'GENE3'}, 'Status': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 1, 10: 2, 11: 0, 12: 0}}
```

Comment: chk SP4 and GENE3 in result  plz. i think not 0-2 but 1-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code**

```
g = df.groupby(['Names1', 'Gene_name'])
g['Status'].agg(lambda x: '-'.join(x.astype('str').sort_values().unique())).unstack()
```

output

```
Gene_name   GENE1   GENE2   GENE3
Names1          
SP1         0-1-2   0-1     NaN
SP2         NaN     2       NaN
SP3         NaN     0       NaN
SP4         NaN     NaN     1-2
SP5         NaN     NaN     0
```

**make desired output**

```
(g['Status'].agg(lambda x: '-'.join(x.astype('str').sort_values().unique()))
 .unstack().rename_axis(index='Name', columns=''))
```

result:

```
        GENE1   GENE2   GENE3
Name            
SP1     0-1-2   0-1     NaN
SP2     NaN     2       NaN
SP3     NaN     0       NaN
SP4     NaN     NaN     1-2
SP5     NaN     NaN     0
```

Answer (score 1):

The above solution would be neater, but just wanted to put out an alternative solution to the same:

```
import numpy as np

names = df['Names1'].unique()  
genes = df['Gene_name'].unique() 
result_df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': names}) 

for gene in genes: 
    values = []
    for name in names: 
        result = '-'.join(map(str, count_df.loc[(count_df['Names1'] == name) & (count_df['Gene_name'] == gene), ['Status']]['Status'].to_numpy()))
        if result == '':
            values.append(np.nan) 
        else:
            values.append(result) 

    result_df[gene] = values 

result_df
```

**Output**

```
        GENE1   GENE2   GENE3
Names            
SP1     0-1-2   0-1     NaN
SP2     NaN     2       NaN
SP3     NaN     0       NaN
SP4     NaN     NaN     1-2
SP5     NaN     NaN     0
```

Answer (score 0):

with using pivot table the solutiont can looks like this:

```
df.pivot_table('Status','Names1','Gene_name',
               aggfunc=lambda x: '-'.join(x.astype(str).unique())).rename_axis(columns=None)
>>>
'''
           GENE1 GENE2 GENE3
Names1                      
SP1        0-1-2   0-1   NaN
SP2          NaN     2   NaN
SP3          NaN     0   NaN
SP4          NaN   NaN   1-2
SP5          NaN   NaN     0
```